# Automate Wine Mouse Clicks

Tags: wine

I have a Windows game that I play on Linux via Wine.  I'd like to automate a few things - it's an old game with a miserable UI.  I can use the XTest interface (xte, xvkbd) to send keyboard events, but I can't figure out how to send mouse clicks.

It seems like Wine ignores the test mouseinput (xte "mouseclick 1" does nothing).  xmodmap and xkbset do allow me to press keys to trigger mouse events, and Wine reads those correctly, but I can't then fake those keys with xte/xvkbd, presumably because the test interface happens higher up on the stack.  I have putzed around with Autohotkey, but I'm not a fan of it's syntax at all and would prefer to just have some python.

Comment: There is no such thing as `autohotkey` in Linux. There is `autokey` though. `autohotkey` is for Windows. So, are you mentioning `autokey` here?

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem with `autokey`? It's darn simple. Just create a new script in it like :

```
mouse.click_relative(50, 700, 1)
```

This at a point located at 50px in x-direction and 700px in y-direction taking upper-left corner as the origin, relative to current active window.